# mongodb getting the oldest of animals map/reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mapreduce

I've never tried map/reduce.

How would I get the oldest of each type of animal?

My data is like this:

```
[
{
  "cateory": "animal",
  "type": "cat",
  "age": 4,
  "id": "a"
},
{
  "cateory": "animal",
  "type": "bird",
  "age": 3,
  "id": "b"
},
{
  "cateory": "animal",
  "type": "cat",
  "age": 7
  "id": "c"
},
{
  "cateory": "animal",
  "type": "bird",
  "age": 4,
  "id": "d"
},
{
  "cateory": "animal",
  "type": "cat",
  "age": 8,
  "id": "e"
},
{
  "cateory": "company",
  "type": "Internet",
  "age": 5,
  "id": "Facebook"
}
]
```

I'm using node-mongodb-native. Thanks!

Comment: if you are using mongoose with mongodb, here is how to implement map/reduce https://gist.github.com/1123688

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map function should look something like this:

```
map = function() {
  emit({type: this.type}, {age: this.age});
}
```

And the reduce function:

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
  maxAge = 0;
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    if (maxAge < v['age']) {
       maxAge = v['age'];
    }
  });

  return {age: maxAge};
}
```

Comment: Only emit something in the map function if

    this.category == 'animal'

Comment: Also, the map-reduce command accepts a `query` parameter which can be used to filter. If you have an index on `type`, then the `query` parameter will save you from running `map()` on several documents.

Comment: @Gates VP yeah thanks, finally found the query parameter in the tests. Freaking no documentation man.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```js
collection.find({type : 'animal'}).sort({animal: -1}).limit(1);
```